# Webdriverio (WDIO) and Cucumber Browser based on Tag

Tags: webdriver-io

How would one setup WDIO to run a scenario on a specific browser based on a cucumber tag. I think I can do it by closing the existing browser instance and then opening a new browser instance in a cucumber before scenario hook, but that is not efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your browser configuration, [you can specify certain test to run in that browser only](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/examples/wdio.conf.js#L74).